# tensorflow and libcudart library issue in AWS sagemaker endpoint creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-ecr

I am trying to deploy a NLP model in AWS Sagemaker Endpoint.
The model image is stored in ECR and pushed into Sagemaker instance.
While building the Docker image, No Error.

when creating the endpoint using the forum (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/realtime-endpoints-deploy-models.html : boto3 inference components) its throwing below error message:

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
```

I tried with copying the `libcudart` package from local to docker image and the runtime environment - No Result

Added the `libcudart` package in the requirement.txt - No result

What could be the potential issue and solution??

Comment: Have you confirmed you can run the container locally say on ec2 or a SageMaker notebook instance? Also make sure you are not bundling any NVIDIA drivers in your container: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/what-is-the-difference-between-libcudart-so-present-in-different-directories-in-linux/266458/2